# Internet Explorer automatically downloading music from site instead of streaming it

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have a music site. It works correctly except for when I enter the site from Internet Explorer. IDM (internet download manager) is downloading music from my site. There is no problem in Chrome and Firefox. Just IE. How can I disable or block the downloading of music from sites in Internet Explorer?

Answer (score 0):

ie doesn't know how to play this stream, he get's so he downloads it. you can get add-ons for IE to prevent that behavior on your LOCAL machine.

you could set headers in php or with your webserver,

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
```

would do the trick in IE if i'm not totally wrong.
But this is not preventing the User from being able to download the Stream. 
If you really want to do that you need to use Microsoft's Silverlight Plugin or another DRM-Player

Comment: I dont want to my music cant download by programs in no way. Just playing. In fine; i want to block all download programs in all browsers and if possible i want to hide links at source codes.